# Proof of open mapping theorem in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

In the standard textbook the author always involves Baire's Category Theorem to prove Uniform Bounded Theorem, but it is not fairly elementary because of the deepness of Baire's Category Theorem. [A really simple elementary proof of the uniform boundedness theorem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.1585.pdf)
  gives a simple proof, and I think this elementary proof essentially is an application of "gliding hump" method. So my questions is

### Can we just use the technical gliding hump method to prove the equivalent theorem, i.e., open mapping theorem?

The first step of  proof for open mapping theorem is applying Baire's category theorem to

$$F\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \overline{T(B(0,n))},$$

where $T$ is a bounded, surjective linear operator and $F$ is a normed space, to show at least one $\overline{T(B(0,n))}$ has nonempty interior. I want to know if this step can be replaced by some elementary techniques?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, as your paper shows? Also, note that the proof in this paper depends on the axiom of depend choice, and so does the Baire category theorem.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thank you sir, I have finished the details of constructing a point $y \in F$, but $y \notin \overline{ T(B(0,n)) }$ for all $n$, but the process is vey similar to the proof of Baire's category theorem, so the use of Baire's category theorem is just a hiding of longish and technical construction?